# アプリからGoogleDrive上のファイルを検索する方法について

Tags: php, google-drive-sdk

アプリで入力したキーワードをもとに、
下記内容で、指定したフォルダIDからキーワードを含むファイルの取得を実施していました。
今まで取得できていたのですが、最近になり取得できなくなってしまいました。
他に取得する方法があれば教えていただきたいです。

"fullText contains 'キーワード' and 'フォルダID' in parents and mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed = false"

キーワードとフォルダ指定をand条件で取得したいのですが、
キーワードのみ、フォルダ指定のみの条件であれば取得できることは確認しています。

Comment: `今まで取得できていたのですが、最近になり取得できなくなってしまいました。`についての詳細は不明ですが、今、表示されたsearch queryをテストしたところ、期待した結果が返されることが分かりました。そのため、状況を理解する必要があると思いました。そこで、問題の詳細をお教えいただけないでしょうか。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
GDrive上にあるファイルをアプリからキーワード検索（全文検索）を行い、ヒットしたファイルをアプリ上で一覧結果で表示しております。

今までは、下記内容で問題なく取得できていたのですが、最近になりキーワード検索をしても検索結果が０件でした返ってこなくなりました。
（フォルダID指定のところがうまく機能していないようでした。）
＞"fullText contains 'キーワード' and 'フォルダID' in parents and mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed = false"

こちらで試行錯誤してみたところ下記に変更することで、期待した検索結果が取得できるようになりました。
＞"fullText contains 'キーワード' and parents in 'フォルダID' and mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed = false"
（修正前）'フォルダID' in parents→（修正後）parents in 'フォルダID' 

このあたりについてAPIの仕様が変わったなどあるか教えていただきたいです。

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。残念ながら、今こちらでテストを行ったところ、`'###folderId###' in parents`, `parents = '###folderId###'`, `parents in '###folderId###'`のそれぞれで同じ結果を得ました。[Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/268baf07f92f3b3962c86c6ea75b786a#3-retrieving-the-file-list-by-searching-the-parent-folder-id) 残念ながら、`（修正前）'フォルダID' in parents→（修正後）parents in 'フォルダID'`については変化はありません。さらに、仕様の変更については今のところ聞いておりません。申し訳ありません。ですが、問題が解決したようで安心しました。

Comment: ご確認ありがとうございます。
もう一点確認させてください。
今回フォルダIDのみの検索であれば、ご指摘いただいた3パターン全て問題なく動作することは確認できたのですが、キーワード検索（fullText）の構文を組み合わせると取得できなくなりました。何か関係あるかわかりますでしょうか？

検索結果取得不可：
fullText contains 'キーワード' and 'フォルダID' in parents
検索結果取得可：
'フォルダID' in parents（キーワードなし）
検索結果取得可：
fullText contains 'キーワード' and parents in 'フォルダID'

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。`fullText contains 'キーワード' and 'フォルダID' in parents`, `fullText contains 'キーワード' and parents in 'フォルダID'`に違いは無く、`'フォルダID' in parents（キーワードなし）`の場合は、フォルダ下のファイルが取得されます。残念ながらそちらの状況を再現できません。